# Bootstrap how to delete padding from header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create an active class for my header menu I try delete padding top and bottom for all element in my header and nothing works.

Here is my code:

```
<header>
              <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                    <div class="container-fluid header-custom">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
                          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img alt="Climatherm" src="img/home.png"></a>
                        </div>
                        <p class="navbar-text pull-right hidden-xs hidden-sm">09 99 99 99 99</p>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="active"><span><a href="#">Plomberie Sanitaires</a></span></li>
                            <li class="active"><span><a href="#">Chauffage Climatisation</a></span></li>
                            <li class="active"><span><a href="#">nouvelles énergies</a></span></li>
                            <li class="active"><span><a href="#">dépannage maintenance</a></span></li>
                            <li class="active"><span><a href="#">Partenaires</a></span></li>
                            <li class="active"><span><a href="#">nous Contacter</a></span></li>
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
      </header>
```

My css code

```
body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.navbar-default {
    background-color: #ed1c24;
    border:none;
    border-radius:0px;
}

.header-custom{
    max-width:1000px;
    padding-top:0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}


.navbar-text{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color:#fff!important;
    background-color:#d80109;
    border-radius:18px;
    padding:8px 20px 8px 30px;
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-bottom:auto;
}

.navbar-text::before{
    content: url(../img/contact.png);
    display:inline-block;
    opacity: 1;
    transform:translate(-13px, 4px);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>span>a {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav{
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navbar-nav li {
     display: inline-block;
     list-style: none;
     margin-left: 10px;
}
.navbar-nav li {
     max-width: 110px; 
     line-height: 40px;
     height: 40px;
     background-color: #000;
}
.navbar-nav li span {
     display: -moz-inline-box; /* FF2 or lower */
     display: inline-block; /* FF3, Opera, Safari */
     line-height: normal;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center;
}
.navbar-nav li span { 
     *display  : inline; /* haslayout for IE6/7 */
}
```

and the result is:

[results of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VHsO.png)

I want to make it like this:

[Result expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqOuT.png)

I tried to search for a solution in different forums and here but nothing works.

Comment: its probably because css defined in bootstrap is overriding your css, and that is because the rule in bootstrap has higher priority. Try using - `header elem.classname`, or `header elem anotherElem .classname`, some longer selectors.

Comment: Can you provide a link if you have hosted this somewhere?

Comment: i didn't host it until now im working in localhost

Comment: @RohitKumar i tried your suggestion but still not work

Comment: I copied your code, my result and your result both are different, You should provide a link OR provide proper code.

Comment: @SiMohamedAmineBya use code inspector to see if `padding` defined by you is applied or not.

Comment: @VishalPanara Yes therse is a different i find that im using a bootstrap with some change but its working good now

Comment: @SiMohamedAmineBya, do you want it like this?[link](https://jsfiddle.net/m1nvuL20/1/)

Comment: @SatejS thanks a lot man it's working now

Comment: Okay, @SiMohamedAmineBya, is the link as per what you required, then i'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @SatejS it's not as i want it exactly the problem is i use height 50px for the container and my menu height 40px

Comment: Alright. Please attach a working model/fiddle the next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this solution feasible? [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/jy9rzf6b/)

I set the height of the buttons the same as the container (50px instead of 40px).

```
.navbar-nav li {
     max-width: 110px; 
     line-height: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background-color: #000;
}
```